# Will this linq display object with latest date?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a list of objects with Same ObjectId and I want to return the one with latest DateOrdered. Is this a good way to doing it?

```
var LatestObject = (from o in Context.Objects 
    where p.ObjectId == ObjectId 
    select p.DateOrdered)
    .ToList()
    .Max();
```

Comment: Are you doing this for each ID in the data set, or do you really only care about one single ID value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it will only display latest date.Not your object, instead you can try:

```
Context.Objects.Where(p => p.ObjectId == ObjectId)
       .OrderByDescending(p => p.DateOrdered)
       .First();
```

Comment: For more information look at [Sorting Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546145.aspx) article

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
var result = Context.Objects.Where(p => p.ObjectId == ObjectId).OrderByDescending(x => x.DateOrdered).FirstOrDefault();
```